# popoup or form mode of the angular devextreme is rendering with [object][object]

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme

In the `popoup` mode of the `devextreme`: `dxo-editing`, UI is rendering `[object][object]`.
UI/Data is rendering perfectly in the view mode without any issue.

My code:

```
    <dxo-editing
        mode="popup"
        [allowUpdating]="true"
        [allowDeleting]="true"
        [allowAdding]="true">
    </dxo-editing>
```

```
<dxi-column dataField="categories" cellTemplate="categoryCellTemplate" [width]="150">
```

```
    <div *dxTemplate="let cct of 'categoryCellTemplate'" class="source-cell">
        <span *ngFor="let category of cct.data.categories">
            <span [ngClass]="category.name.toLowerCase() ?? 'no-category'" class="source-item">{{category?.name}}</span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Am I missing anything ? BTW trying Angular/devextreme first time.

Comment: Can you please share more information?  I'm not sure where [object][object] is being rendered, but I'm assuming it is the cell contents/template?  Can you try using the JsonPipe to see what the object looks like?  If it is the cell template showing [object][object], then try `{{category?.name | json}}`

Comment: if you are talking about the pop form showing [object][object], then you need to help the form understand how to render the fields in their editing form.  Please see: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/DataGrid/Editing/#User_Interaction/Popup_Mode  and https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/devextreme-datagrid-custom-editing-form/blob/22.2.5%2B/Angular/src/app/app.component.html  and  https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/devextreme-datagrid-show-grid-in-popup-edit-form/blob/21.1.3%2B/Angular/src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cellTemplate` has nothing to do with your popup. I guess you are using the `dx-data-grid` component. Creating a cell template for a column will only change the appearance of the cell for that specific column inside your data grid.

In the popup there will be a default editor, trying to display an array of objects. DevExtreme tries to use a `dx-tag-box` or a `dx-select-box` to render an array. This tag box does not know how to interpret your array of `categories`.

Here is an example how you could solve this issue:

1. Use the [`editCellTemplate`](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#editCellTemplate) to change the appearance of the editor inside the popup form.
2. Use the [`calculateDisplayValue`](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#calculateDisplayValue) to change the appearance inside the data grid column cells. Instead of using the `cellTemplate` like you are doing.

```html
<dxi-column
    dataField="categories"
    editCellTemplate="categoryEditCellTemplate"
    [calculateDisplayValue]="calculateCategoriyDisplayValue">
</dxi-column>


<!-- this is for using a tag box inside the popup form to be able to select multiple categories based on their id -->
<div *dxTemplate="let cct of 'categoryEditCellTemplate'" class="source-cell">
    <dx-tag-box [dataSource]="categories" valueExpr="id" displayExpr="name" [(value)]="cct.data.categories"></dx-tag-box>
</div>
```

```js
class MyComponent {

    constructor() {
        this.calculateCategoriyDisplayValue = this.calculateCategoriyDisplayValue.bind(this);
    }

    rows: { categories: number[] }[] = [
        { categories: [1,2] },
        { categories: [2,3] },
        { categories: [1] },
    ];

    categories: { id: number; name: string; }[] = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Category1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Category2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Category3' }
    ];

    // this is for showing category names inside the categories column cells
    calculateCategoriyDisplayValue(rowData: {categories: number[]}) {
        if (rowData.categories == null) return;
        return rowData.categories.map(id => this.categories.find(c => c.id == id)?.name).filter(x => x != null).join(', ');
    }
}
```

I recommend changing your data model so you have only the category ids inside the array instead of objects, like i did in my example. This will make it easier.